# How to stream video in php

Tags: php, flash

I have to stream videos in my php site? how to do that. any body knows any free flash player given sites link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JW FLV Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) can stream (see [this page](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Formats))